# Regex to separate custom uploaded video

Tags: regex

I need to separate custom uploaded videos and some videos with `-` or `_` are not being detected. Can anyone help me with my code?

```
$services_regexp = array("#^[\w\s]+\.(?P<format>[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5})#" => 'local',`
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of the data and your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

`[\w\s]+`, which you appear to be using for the filename before the extension, only matches alphanumeric characters (`\w` is a shortcut for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) and whitespace (`\s`). If you want to also allow a dash, then you need to add it at the end of the character class:

```
"#^[\w\s-]+\.(?P<format>[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5})#"
```

The underscore is already contained in `\w`.